# CI - An error was encountered

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, dwoo

I have the following error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> exception 'Dwoo_Compilation_Exception' with message 'Compilation error at line 618 in "string:" : Parse error in ": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1, "prevArrow" : ".prev-btn", "nextArrow": ".next-btn" }'>

This is my code:

```
<div class="team-slider enable-stick-slider" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1, "prevArrow" : ".prev-btn", "nextArrow": ".next-btn" }'>
```

Comment: Try using double quote (`"`) instead of single quotes for `data-slick`, and single quotes inside.

Comment: Unfortunately. It gives the same error.

Comment: @TheDude why would that make any difference?

Comment: It appears to be valid JSON. Was trying to think of a reason why it wouldn't be able to parse that string.

Comment: @RobbieAverill, because [The Dude abides](http://lifewithjoliefete.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/fc550x550brown.u1.jpg). (*Movie reference.*) On topic, I suppose it could possibly be helpful if there was some weird, internal parsing error with the compiler. In which case, switching the quotes could fix that problem. However, CodeIgniter has been around for something like 10 years now, so I would venture to guess that they probably have worked out any and all bugs like that.